# AWS ECS | CPU allocated to a container

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, cpu, amazon-ecs

I have a task that has task memory of 2GB (2048) and task cpu of 1 vCPU.
I have two containers inside that task -
One with hard/soft memory limit of 2048 and 1024 cpu units
and one that the memory limit is not defined or and 0 cpu units.

I couldn't find a proper explanation about the partition of the memory and CPU between the two containers.

That this mean that the first container has a priority to get all the cpu in case of need and the other container will settle for cpu leftovers?
I couldn't find a clear answer.

Thank you!

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/how-amazon-ecs-manages-cpu-and-memory-resources/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct, that the container with no resource allocations will simply consume the resources left over from the other container.

This [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/how-amazon-ecs-manages-cpu-and-memory-resources/) explains how resources are partitioned. This is the passage that is relevant to your question.

> if containers are not using their allotted CPU units, other containers
> can use that capacity. When capacity is not used, any container can
> burst to use that spare capacity. CPU shares control the amount of CPU
> capacity available when there is CPU contention; that is, multiple
> containers attempting to use the CPU at the same time.
>
> if there is
> spare capacity on the host (because the sum of all CPU units across
> all containers across all tasks is less than the available capacity on
> the host) the excess capacity on the host is re-partitioned
> proportionally to all of the containers if/when they need it